# What would force the "illuminati" to cull the world?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, earth-like

### Premise

This is an uncomfortable topic, perhaps even bordering on distasteful. That being said, the world I have in mind will not be complete unless I can settle on a threshold that the "illuminati" would use as a sign for their culling to begin. First a quick disambiguation of terms:

- "illuminati" - this is the archetypal group of shadow-funding, deep-state oligarchs. Not too much is known of them, but assume they exist and they will be the ones doing the culling. It's best not to ask too much about them! Everything except their motives is likely out of scope.
- "cull" - this term, albeit a distasteful one (as its usually in the context of animals/ecology), is the act of reducing the population who possess undesirable characteristics.

That is a good start, but it veritably begs the question: what is the "undesirable characteristic," What's the motive? That's where my world falls apart. I can't think of a realistic motive whose course of action was unequivocally a culling of the world population. Here is a small list of motives I researched and rejected:

- **They know too much:** The age of information, computers and interconnectedness threaten to expose the illuminati. **Rejected
  because:** cull as they might, the illuminati might still lose the
  cyber war. It would be better to cull the internet.
- **They blight our world:** While clambering on their hamster wheel, the masses have soiled the Earth with plastic waste, waste water and
  worse. Also they have caused many of the "illuminati's" favorite
  vacation resorts to sink below sea level. **Rejected because:**
  killing the masses after they made such a big mess seems untimely;
  better to keep them around until they fix things. Also it makes the
  illuminati comically similar to Green Peace.

### Question

What is a realistic motive to cull the population? Which heuristic would the "illuminati" be looking at carefully for when to begin the cull? So in other words I'd like a general theory but also something quantifiable, ideally anyway.

**Further Clarifications**

- How the illuminati cull the population is out of scope, just assume they can should the need arise
- You may try to salvage one of my rejected ideas if you see hope in it or submit a new one of your own
- Assume everything to be Earth-like.
- Who's being culled? The whole world's population
- Timeframe: flexible, fast culls or slow culls are allowed
- **Quality Metric:** The fewer substitutes to culling the population the better. This means that a good answer will suggest a motive where the only logical outcome is to cull the population. (not something else, like take out the satellites or the electric grid)

Comment: none, the more people have acces to "right" information the more it can be distorted thus creating 50 versions of flat earth. People cull themself.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Excellent counter point; that's certainly a plot twist I didn't consider yet.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY - Well, the internet has brought by far more correct/valuable information to the population than misinformation. What was the alternative prior to that? Mainstream media? Well, good luck with that not misinforming you... I think people have already a good grasp on the credibility of mainstream media. So sure, you get the occasional Flat Earth or other conspiracy theories, but in contrary to basically *the entire history of humanity*, now you can actually get closer to the truth than ever before. The internet is not the friend of the powers that be.

Comment: @Battle The internet didn't bring anything. The information needed to exist outside to be put into internet. For any information that is true you can couter it or warp with other information. Your "source" is as good as anyone else. It is easier to do peer review or discard information when you can't verify it but it also work against movies with yellow subs.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY - If I want to find out how to do or build X, I may find 100 ways to do it, 10 which are less effective and 1 which is not working. 100 years ago I simply wouldn't even know where to start finding information about it. Maybe I'd finally find someone who'd give me a method which doesn't work. You are setting unreachable standards to the internet, just so that you can claim it is a source of misinformation, while the opposite is true - especially compared to everything prior to the internet. You literally have access to every conceivable perspective on any topic out there.

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: @Battle and SZCZERZO KŁY: This is not the place for a "fake news" argument.

Comment: Arash: This question appears to fall within the off-topic text of the help center: "If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." You're asking about the motivations of an organization. Voting to close as _too story-based_.

Comment: Please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problem with questions like this is they are not objective, are prone to being [POB](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437), and are too story-based.  In short: you've asked us to provide a critical plot point for your story, not answer a question about a rule of your world.

Answer (score 9):

If they are **scientific** and ruthless, Global Warming is a good excuse.

I am a PhD, a mathematician and statistician, a full time research scientist: There is no stopping global warming; this is my firm opinion. There will be an ecological disaster, it will destroy countries, make parts of the Earth near the equator uninhabitable, destroy food crops, and on and on. People will not change, recycle, or switch to clean energy fast enough, because they'd have to give up 90% of their lifestyle. They just aren't going to do it! Ever! They won't live without air-conditioning, motored vehicles, air travel, power equipment, plastics, refrigeration, robotic manufacturing. They just won't.

If the Illuminati are ***truly*** the brightest and smartest people on the planet, and they believe this too, the only thing that stops this runaway train is blowing it up: Doing away with most of the people, to prevent them from producing all their waste heat, garbage, plastic, and waste.

The Illuminati may feel the world is at a tipping point, and it is their job, for the sake of *continuing* humanity, to kill 90% of humanity. Because they believe 90% or more will die in the ecological apocalypse anyway.

And the choice of which 10% get to live and where must be made by them. Because if they let it happen randomly then the Earth is back to the stone age, but if they can do it selectively, there will be large enough concentrations of humans left that humanity will continue on the path of modern levels of technology, which they support and believe may increase the number of supportable humans on Earth, in space and eventually on other planets.

The Illuminati determine they can avoid the apocalypse, that the Earth can indefinitely tolerate and recycle the waste produced by about 1 billion people, not eight or nine or ten billion. Thus it is up to them to start enforcing that.

For the love of humanity, of course.

Comment: or similarly, the increase in population plus depletion of resources is going to lead to nuclear war. Culling the population, much like with animals, acts as a pressure valve, ensuring that the Earth is habitable for the rest.